# I am running 1000 parallel simulations in R on a cluster. What is the best way to manage and recombine the results after?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I currently have a simulation that I need to loop over 1000 times before averaging the results. Currently, I am putting the results in a list with 1000 entires. However, each simulation takes about 1 hour. As a result, I have set-up a parallel simulation coding scheme whereby I can sent my coding to be executed in parallel on a cluster.

Currently, it looks like I will be having 1000 .RData files, of which I will try to combine later. I have made sure that the variables of interest in each of the .RData files have been numbered already to avoid ambiguity.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a more efficient method than this? Would there be a way to combine all the results efficiently without having open 1000 .Rdata files? Thanks!

Comment: Probably use `saveRDS` rather than `save`. Saving separate files is how I do it. If the resulting files are small enough, you could write a clean up script that goes in, reads the files, stores each to a list, and then removes the files (if you don't like the clutter).

Comment: If you used the right package, R could probably do this for you automatically via something like `parLapply`. Maybe try the `future` and/or `batchtools` packages?

Comment: @Imo What is the difference between `saveRDS` and `save`? Is it less likely to be corrupt?